# Web.ApplyTheme() for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, theme

I want to apply one of the default themes to my SharePoint site.
I found [Web.ApplyTheme()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.applytheme.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which requires

- string colorPaletteUrl,
- string fontSchemeUrl,
- string backgroundImageUrl,
- bool shareGenerated

I have tried to use one of the existing colorPalettes and fontSchemes found under Designer Gallery:
[image]

```
$ctx.Web.ApplyTheme("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/powie1/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette001","https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/powie1/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme001.spfont",$null, $true)
```

and url with .spcolor extension:

```
$ctx.Web.ApplyTheme("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/powie1/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette001","https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/powie1/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme001.spfont",$null, $true)
```

but I am receiving an error

> Exception calling "ApplyTheme" with "4" argument(s): "The
>   'colorPaletteUrl' argument is invalid."

How can I assign a theme to a SharePoint Online site?

Comment: Check if this is helpful http://sprider.org/2015/03/24/o365-sharepoint-online-apply-theme-csom-powershell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice in both of your given code examples the `Palette001` is without `.spcolor` extension. I suspect this could be the issue.

Refer screen shot which show `Palatte001` with extension.

[image]

I have not tested this code but you can try using below improvements

Improving your code with added `.spcolor` extension:

```
$ctx.Web.ApplyTheme("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/powie1/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette001.spcolor","https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/powie1/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme001.spfont",$null, $true)
```

Now if we consider $null argument as mentioned by @Anuja, we can improve further.

```
$bgImageUrl = Out-Null
$ctx.Web.ApplyTheme("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/powie1/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette001.spcolor", "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/powie1/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme001.spfont", $bgImageUrl, $true)
```

Lastly referring from [CSOM + PowerShell: Setting Theme on Site](http://www.bfcnetworks.com/blogs/alexpearce/csom-powershell-setting-theme-on-site/), the urls are relative here.

```
$web.ApplyTheme( "/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette001.spcolor", "/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme001.spfont", $bgImageUrl, $true)
$web.update()
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with Out-Null instead of $null or null or Empty String

follow this link for more information http://sprider.org/2015/03/24/o365-sharepoint-online-apply-theme-csom-powershell/